# Reading from simple Logs file with elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am running ElasticSearch.bat *(cluster)* and kibana.bat on windows and as I know Elasticsearch index Json formats...

I have a 3 SpringBoot projects with log files (exemple: dd-mm-yyyy.log ) generated By log4j
[image]
Here my questions:

Is there any way to make my projects as nodes and **read, index and search from those logs** ?

If no is there any change to make it possible ?

***My goal is to search a string into those logs with ElasticSearch***

Thank you

Comment: Technically the correct stack for this is `Filebeat -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch -> Kibana` install Filebeat agent to your app nodes. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html You can skip `Logstash` if your logs are already in a good format to be indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [install Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-getting-started.html)

You [configure Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-configuration.html) by listing the paths to your log files

This should index your logs in Elasticsearch. If you want to be able to query against logs from only a single application, the records will contain a "source" field which is the full path to the log file. You can use this to specify which logs to query.

You can also add custom fields in the Filebeat config if you want to distinguish between log sources. Adapting the [example from the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#configuration-fields) assuming the applications are logging into folders c:/app1/logs/ and c:/app2/logs/

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - 'c:/app1/logs/*.log'
  fields:
    app: 1
  field_under_root: true
- type: log
  paths:
    - 'c:/app2/logs/*.log'
  fields:
    app: 2
  fields_under_root: true
```